# Embedded Java Amqp broker with Federation capabilities

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, microservices

I want to have micro services that communicate with amqp messages. I want to have a local queue that, when a connection is established to the RabbitMQ-server, sends/federates all the messages from the local queue to the server.

I looked at Apache Qpid, but the Java Broker doesn't have federation capabilities yet (there is a proposal for it).

Is there another small embedded java amqp broker that can work?
Or is there some other java tool to actively send messages from a local queue to the remote servers?